# how read cookie value using javascript created in Asp.net C#

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using ASP.net MVC 2.0 , i want to set Cookie from my Controller and read it from java Script i there any way to do so i have used following code in controller

```
HttpCookie ActiveTabs = new HttpCookie("tabs");
ActiveTabs.Values["top_navi_link"] = "ViewConference";
Response.Cookies.Add(ActiveTabs);
```

how to read it from java script.

Comment: Use Google. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: @SOliver, `w3schools`? Seriously? There are also [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Yes seriously; they provide a adequate solution to the OP's problem. w3fools are claiming that there is a lot of questionable content on the site, not that every item on it is wrong.

Comment: I agree with SOliver here.  *Most* of W3Schools is good info, but there are quite a few bad ones.  And the bulk of the "bad ones" are very nitpicky.

Answer (score 4):

Use this jquery `jquery-cookies.js` which make it easy:

```
var cookiedata = $.cookie('top_navi_link');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(document.cookie);
</script>
```

There are also some jquery plugins such as [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) which might simplify this task.